# TvOs : is there a way to know when tv is turned off / on?

Tags: tvos, television

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763217/detect-if-tv-is-turned-off-on-tvos) but the author self answered and his answer doesn't provide what I need.

I would like to know if there is a way on tvOs to detect or to be notified when the TV is turned ON / OFF?